# Circular button becomes rounded rectangle after size increase

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I created a circular button in my iOS app and after changing the auto layout width and height constraints (so that the button is bigger) it is now a rounded rectangle instead of a circle.

I have a UIButton defined in Main.storyboard and as IBOutlet in ViewController.swift ...

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
```

In `viewDidLoad()` I am changing .cornerRadius at runtime to make it a circle ...

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2.0
```

This approach worked *perfectly* for my app until I changed the height / width of the UIButton. I am stumped as to why the button is no longer a circle. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead?

Comment: Yes... the UIButton is circular again. I'm still confused why it worked in `viewDidLoad()` previously, and now required `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto Layout happens after `viewDidLoad`, so you need to move your adjustment to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` so that the frame size will be set to the correct size.

Comment: Ah, makes perfect sense. As I was typing my comment I immediately thought of the Auto Layout constraints that were added.